# how to obtain the number of single character for each item contained withing a object

Tags: python, for-loop, character, counting

I am trying using a for loop to count the characters within this object:

```
S = "Hello World"
d = S.split()
d
['Hello', 'World']

for i in (0,len(d)):
    print(len(d[i]))
```

However, I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 2, in <module>
    print(len(n[i]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could anyone explain where this error come from and how to possibly fix it?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `print(len(d[i]))`, what values of `i` do you think are valid? Why? In your own words, where the code says `for i in (0,len(d)):`, what values do you think `i` will end up having? Why? Next: *What is the intended purpose of the loop*? You want to do something with each *element of the list*, right? In your own words, what is your understanding of how `for` loops work in Python? (If you cannot answer these questions, you should try working through a Python tutorial first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len()` reports the length of the list - if there is 1 item in the list, it is of length 1 -- the *index* of that element is 0.

```
len(['one element']) == 1
```

Indexing is 0 based:

```
 k = ['one element']
 k[0] == "one element"
```

You use a tuple of `(0, len(d))`: `len(d)` is 1 bigger then the biggest possible index of *your* list because indexing starts at 0.

> ```
> for i in (0,len(d)):    # (0,2)
>     print(len(d[i]))    # d[2] is out of index
> ```

Hence: `list index out of range`

Use `range(len(d))` instead - or even better:

```
for element in d:
    print(len(element))   # to print all
```